# Difference between std::array begin() and data()

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

What is the difference between `std::array` method `begin()` and `data()`? For example:

```cpp
std::array<int, 5> = { /* numbers */ };
int* it = array.begin();
int* data = array.data();
// it and data are same here
```

Can they be different depending upon the type? Or maybe there is no difference and these methods are just there to match other c++ data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same, in concept.

What [`std::array::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin) returns is an [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array#Member_types), whose type is implementation-defined; it could be pointer as [`std::array::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) returns (pointer satisfies the requirement of iterator), but doesn't have to be.

This code compiles or not depends on implementation, for example, this code won't compile with [MSVC](https://rextester.com/AGJ95035) but compiles with [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2JG36Cyn0USGUE6M).

> ```
> Error(s):
> source_file.cpp(7): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,5>' to 'int *'
>         with
>         [
>             _Ty=int
>         ]
> source_file.cpp(7): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Both are not same accually. `std::array::data` return type is `value_type` and `std::array::begin` return type is an `iterator`.

`std::array::begin` returns an iterator pointing to the first element but `std::array::data` returns a pointer to the first element in the array object.

`iterator` is  [random access iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/) types and there is a implementation for it and `value_type` defined in array as an alias of its first template parameter (T).